# instance.show is not a function error when trying to display tippy.js after 5 seconds on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tippyjs

I am using tippyJS to show a text popup on hover but I also want to display this popup after 5 seconds on pageload so I did this:

```
const instance = tippy('.tooltippy', {
    trigger: 'mouseenter',
    allowHTML: true,
    placement: 'left',
    animation: 'scale-subtle',
    interactive: true,
    content: function (reference) {
        return reference.querySelector('.tooltipcontent');
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  instance.show();
}, 5000);
```

But after 5 seconds I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: instance.show is not a function
```

While my tippyjs works fine.

My html:

```
<span class="whatsappicon tooltippy" title="Chat met ons!">
  <span class="whaplabel tooltipcontent">Stel je vraag!</span>
  <a href="url" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/custom/whatsapp_online.png" alt="Open Whatsapp">
  </a>
</span>
```

What can I do to open this tippy after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my question since I did not see you assigned it directly to an HTMLCollection. Tippy needs to be binded to NodeList or Element type, so we need to get the element first and assign it to it.

This example should work:

```js
const tooltippy = document.getElementById('tooltippy')

const instance = tippy(tooltippy, {
    trigger: 'mouseenter',
    allowHTML: true,
    placement: 'left',
    animation: 'scale-subtle',
    interactive: true,
    content: function (reference) {
        return reference.querySelector('.tooltipcontent');
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
  instance.show();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6/dist/tippy-bundle.umd.js"></script>

<span class="whatsappicon" id="tooltippy" title="Chat met ons!">
  <span class="whaplabel tooltipcontent">Stel je vraag!</span>
  <a href="url" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/custom/whatsapp_online.png" alt="Open Whatsapp">
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get this message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'tippy' before initialization`. Does it still work this way? Because I use v6 instead of v5.

Comment: Ah I see, updated my answer with a working example.